# AWSでLambda関数を作成する時に関数に対してロールの割り当てができません

Tags: aws, aws-lambda

AWSLambdaで関数を作成しようとしていたのですが、ロールの割り当てができずエラーが出てしまいます。
Lambdaのページから、関数の作成→一から作成と進んで、関数名・ランタイムの箇所を入力し、デフォルト実行ロールの変更の箇所は「AWS ポリシーテンプレートから新しいロールを作成」を選択し、ポリシーテンプレートオプションは「基本的なLambda@edgeアクセス権限（CloudFrontトリガーの場合）」を選択しました。
それで、関数の作成ボタンを押したところ、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
User: arn:aws:iam::<私のIAM> is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<ロールのIAM>:role/service-role/basic-lambda-edge-access with an explicit deny
```

エラーメッセージに合わせて、以下のようなポリシーを作成し、私のIAMにアタッチしたのですが、同様のエラーメッセージが出てしまいます。

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:user/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

どのような権限を私のIAMユーザーに割り当てれば関数を作成することがでるか、アドバイスをいただきたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ドキュメントを確認したところ、AWSではLambda開発用のマネージドポリシーが用意されているようです。
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html

また、上記ドキュメントの中では`AWSLambdaFullAccess`とありますがこちらは非推奨となり、現在は`AWSLambda_FullAccess`というロールが用意されているとのことです。
https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess$jsonEditor

見たところCreateRoleは含まれていなさそうなので直接の解決にはならないかもしれず恐縮ですが、その他Lambda開発に必要そうな権限がリストアップされていたため投稿させて頂きました。ご参考頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。
エラーの原因なのですが、以前ちょっとやらかした事によってAWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineというポリシーが私のIAMに付与されていた事でした。
詳細に情報提供していただきありがとうございました。

Comment: なるほどそういうことだったんですね。解決されたようでよかったです！